# Add styling to imported sql data using php

Tags: php, sql

I'm quite new to php and sql and was wondering how i style the data correctly, so that it is displayed in a table rather than block text (see picture to see what i mean)
[image]

This is my php code that i have used.

```
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password) 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("isongs",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select examples");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT tbl_artists.artistname, tbl_songs.songtitle, tbl_songs.yearrelease, tbl_artists.genre, tbl_songs.price
FROM tbl_artists INNER JOIN tbl_songs ON tbl_artists.artistID = tbl_songs.artistID;");
if(!$result) { die(mysql_error()); }

//fetch the data from the database 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
//echo "Song:".$row{'songtitle'}." Year Released:".$row{'yearrelease'}."Price:".$row{'price'}."<br>";*/
echo "Artist:". $row[0]. " Song:". $row[1]. " Year Released:". $row[2] . " Genre:". $row[3] . " Price:". $row[4] . "<br>"; //display the results
}
//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should use HTML table for that, PHP is server side language, not meant for styling.

Comment: Please use mysqli or PDO, mysql is now deprecated and VERY in-secure

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a serious project, only something for my university, so it shouldn't matter how secure it is.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't style your data. All it can do is retrieve the data from your database and put it on your webpage. What you need to do is style that data using HTML and CSS.

For example:

```html
<div>
  <p>Artist: <?php echo $row[0]; ?></p> 
  <p>Song: <?php echo $row[1]; ?></p> 
  <p>Year Released: <?php echo $row[2]; ?></p> 
  <p>Genre: <?php echo $row[3]; ?></p>
  <p>Price: <?php echo $row[4]; ?></p>  
</div>
```

Comment: I eventually worked it out, but thank you nonetheless.